# I am failing to build gudev with JHBuild

Tags: linux, gnome, compiling

When I run `jhbuild buildone gudev` I get:

```
<SNIP>
Making all in .
  CC     extras/gudev/extras_gudev_libgudev_1_0_la-gudevclient.lo
  CC     extras/gudev/extras_gudev_libgudev_1_0_la-gudevdevice.lo
  CC     extras/gudev/extras_gudev_libgudev_1_0_la-gudevmarshal.lo
  CC     extras/gudev/extras_gudev_libgudev_1_0_la-gudevenumtypes.lo
  CCLD   extras/gudev/libgudev-1.0.la
  GEN    extras/gudev/GUdev-1.0.gir
/opt/gnome/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.5.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [extras/gudev/GUdev-1.0.gir] Error 127
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
*** Error during phase build of gudev: ########## Error running make   *** [1/1]
```

**NOTES**:

- I verified that I do have **/opt/gnome/lib/libpython2.5.so.1.0**.
- At time of writing, I'm running latest JHBuild.
- I used `jhbuild bootstrap --ignore-system` to avoid any incompatibilities that may arise from my Debian packages. Note that the Python 2.5 so file is built and installed by this command.

Answer (score 1):

You've installed a shared library in a non-standard location, so it's not found.

If you want the libraries in `/opt/gnome/lib` to be available automatically to all programs, add this directory to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, then run `ldconfig` (as root). If `/etc/ld.so.conf` contains a line like `include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`, rather than add your entry directly to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, create a file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/tshepang.conf` and add `/opt/gnome/lib` to that file.

If you only want the libraries in `/opt/gnome/lib` to be available on request, or don't have root permissions, add that directory to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. (It's a colon-separated list, just like `PATH`, but for libraries instead of executables.)

A third possibility is to tell the `/opt/gnome/bin/python` binary to look for libraries in `/opt/gnome/lib`, but you have to do that when you build the executable. Check the JHBuild documentation for a setting like “[rpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath_%28linking%29)” or “runtime library path”.

Comment: JHBuild runs this `./configure --prefix /opt/gnome --libdir '/opt/gnome/lib'`.

Comment: @Tshepang: Try running `configure` (or JHBuild itself) with `LDFLAGS='-rpath /opt/gnome/lib'` so that the generated binaries will look for shared libraries in `/opt/gnome/lib`. The option `--libdir` is useless here; it controls where libraries that you're building are installed, but `--prefix` already sets that same value.